# Publish called (used) functions in matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I publish called functions in matlab ? When I click on Publish with the script file I would like the functions being called also to be a part of the published document. In 2016b this seems inbuilt but I dont see this in 2015a. I also do not find any sufficient documentations on this difference.

Example:

```
%% HW-5 Q.1.a
% clear command screen and close all open figures if present
clc;
close all;

% display title: HW-#-Question.Number.SubSection
disp('HW-5-Q.1.a');
disp('Start of Program!');
A = 5;
B = 2;
res = 'The result is: ';
GetSum(A, B, res);
GetDiff(A,B, res);
disp('End of Program!');

function [ ] = GetDiff( num1, num2, StringRes )
%GETDIFF Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
R = num1 - num2;
X = ['For Sum: ', StringRes, num2str(R)];
disp(X);
end

function [ ] = GetSum( num1, num2, StringRes )
%GETSUM Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
R = num1 + num2;
X = ['For Sum: ', StringRes, num2str(R)];
disp(X);
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the issue is. R2015a has the same "Include Code" option as R2016b.

Comment: well, the 'include code' is set to true. And yet, I do not see the functions being published.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is not possible in 2015a because the ability to include function code within scripts (instead in a separated file) was introduced only in 2016b.

https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions-in-scripts.html

If you want to do so in 2015a, you should put the functions GetDiff and GetSum in separated m-files. Then, in your main script, add the following publishing markup:

```
%% 
% <include>GetDiff.m</include>
% 
% <include>GetSum.m</include>
```